# windows services recommendation (win 10)

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services

I have specific project. Goal is to detect when there is created txt file in specific folder on windows 10. The application, procedure or service then must execute application (exe) that do something with this file. This is repeated every, for example, 5 seconds. And service must start on boot.

I tried researching on windows services, but because i'm not native to C# and window platform generally i was unable to create successful service.

If someone knew good tutorials or materials on this topic i would be grateful.

Comment: Have a look at a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830565/using-a-filesystemwatcher-with-windows-service).

Answer (score 0):

For fast start go through this tutorials
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14353/creating-a-basic-windows-service-in-c and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer